# Safari and .htaccess .htpasswd leads to status 401

Tags: .htaccess, safari, http-error-401.2

I have basic .htaccess authentication for my development server like this:

```
AuthName "Developer Demo"
AuthType Basic 
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd 
require valid-user
```

It works fine in all browsers but in safari and on iOS devices. After authenticating .html, .css, .svg, and .tff files are loaded. But the .js files get a status 401.
Any idea why that happens?

I created the .htpasswd content with this generator: https://www.web2generators.com/apache-tools/htpasswd-generator

Comment: How are the `.js` files loaded? Any differently to the CSS and other resources?

Comment: It's an Angular app with only static content served from an Apache server. All files are served the same.